# Why does ColdFusion page not timeout when setting requestTimeout?

Tags: multithreading, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I have a ColdFusion page with the following code:

```
<cfscript>
    setting requestTimeout=2;

    thread action="sleep" duration=3000;

    writeOutput("Hello World");
</cfscript>
```

When I request this page, it loads after 3 seconds and I see "Hello World". Shouldn't this page timeout, since the `requestTimeout` is set to 2 seconds?

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding the documentation, `thread action="sleep" duration=3000;` will pause the newly created thread, not the currently running one. So, basically, you are spinning up a new thread (that does nothing) and pausing it for 3 seconds. But, since it is a thread, it doesn't affect the time it takes to run the current thread.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I was just trying to create a simple way to force a timeout without creating an endless loop. But, when I replace the thread with "while(1=1){}" the page still won't timeout.

Comment: A more valid test would be to have `sleep(3000)` as the second command.

Comment: My previous comment sounded good in theory, but when I ran it on trycf.com, the code did not time out.

Comment: @DanBracuk - your suggestion works in Lucee